# Flutter: Share fire directly (PDF)

Tags: flutter, pdf, share

It's possibile to share directly a Pdf file in flutter? I'm using Share_Plus plugin but it only support url or direct path.

My case:

1. Pdf uploaded on firebase
2. I retrive the URL
3. tried to use URI to file but I can't find the direct path to use with share_plus

The only solution is to save the file in the local storage of the phone and then retrieve di path and use with share_plus?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Storage. Files are url-referable from there.
Read all about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage

Comment: I know that..but I can't share the Pdf directly with the URL..